# jQuery Switch Case Plugin?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I know the switch case statement is inherent to javascript and you can't change it. I'm still learning javascript and jQuery so I can get by, but I don't know enough to write something that might be on the level of jQuery itself. So, take this as an idea or a question about if this idea is feasible.

This is my idea, a switch case statement that can use objects... which can be used something like this:

```
switch( $(this) ){

 case .hasClass('foo'):
  // do something
  break;

 case .filter('.bar').attr('id') == 'foo':
  // do something else
  break;

}
```

---

Edit: Even something like this would be nice  (possibly a more reasonable idea)...

```
switch ($(this).hasClass()) {

 case 'foo':
  alert('found a foo!');
  break;

 case 'bar':
  alert('found a bar!');
  break;

}
```

Comment: *shrug* seemed like the right thing to do?

Comment: LOL, now that I've had some time to think about this - I've included a second more reasonable example. Also, I made this a community wiki because there may not ever be an answer to this question. It's more of an idea to see if others might find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often switches are not the best way to solve a problem, but using jQuery you could make a plugin that works kind of like a switch statement:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.switchClasses = function(switches) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var that = this;
            $.each(this.attr("class").split(' '), function(i, class) {
                var func = switches[class];
                if(func)
                    func.apply(that, class);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You would use the plugin like so:

```
$(this).switchClasses(
    {
        "class1":
        function(class) {
            // Do something for this class, 
            // the "this" variable is the jquery object that matched the class
        },

        "class2":
        function(class) {

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I always loved using object literals as quick switch statements. +1

Answer (score 1):

First, the switch statement only works on int's.  I'm not sure why javascript kept this limitation from C/C++, but it is there.

Using nested if-then-else blocks instead of a switch can lead to highly unreadable code, if you're dealing with more than a handful of options.

However, just like in C and C++, there are workarounds, and this one involves using "break" like a goto, which are not always evil.  This is a situation (a large amount of nested if-the-else's) where goto would make the code more efficient and readable.  In C/C++ you would implement this using goto's with the label being at the end of the series of if's (where the end of switch bracket is now), and skip jumping into a switch context.

```
switch (1) { //yes, that is a hardcoded 1, we only want the switch block for the break keyword
    if (yourString == "Case 1") {
        do_stuff_1();
        break; // well, we're done, let's get out of here.
    }

//implicit else - if you matched the first one, you'd be out of here

    if (yourString == "Case 2") {
        do_stuff_2();
        break; // well, we're done, let's get out of here.
    }

    // etc.....

    default:
        do_error_condition();
} //end of switch
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with a normal `if/else`?

```
inst = $(this);

if (inst.hasClass('foo')) {
    // do something
} else if (inst.filter('.bar').attr('id') == 'foo') {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Readability after more than one or two cases ?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch on `element.attr('class')` if you're dealing with one class name.

If you're dealing with more than one you can do `element.attr('class').split(/\s+/)` and check for the classes name in that array.

I also think you might want to take a look at `.is()`. You can do things like `if( element.is('a.foo') ) console.log( 'This is a link with a 'foo' class.' );`

You might want to change your approach though. I can't see this being the most efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.switchClasses = function(switches) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var that = this;
            $.each(this.attr("class").split(' '), function(i, classname) {
                var func = switches[classname];
                if(func){
                    func.apply(that, classname);
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

'class' is a reserved name,
and I added some missing parenthesis