# switch case statement based one of many classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement a switch case statement like this:

```
switch (active.attr('class')){
    case "video": ...

        case "slideshow": ...
...
```

The problem is, that "video" and "slideshow" each are one of three classes the div I'm trying to target has, therefor it doesn't match the case...

How would I basically say "video is a part of attr('class')" ?

Thanks, 
Lutz

Comment: Using jQuery with the attr? If so add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using `jQuery`, which offers two methods for that:

- [`.is()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
- [`.hasClass()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

So you can either call:

```
if( active.hasClass('video') ) { }
```

or

```
if( active.is('.video') ) { }
```

Notice that `.is()` requires a more specific pattern with the leading `.` but it you can determine lots of other things too like `.is('div')` etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works of course.. I was standing in my own way because i was so focused on the switch-statement...

Comment: `.hasClass` is much faster than `.is` . Its performance is comparable to pure javascript (check out http://jsperf.com/jquery-is-vs-hasclass ) try to use `.hasClass` if you can, especially if you are going through a lot of 'cases'

Answer (score 4):

You could perhaps try and split the string.
From the top of my head:

```
var classes = active.attr('class').split(' ');
foreach(var c in classes) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'video'
        ...
        case 'slideshow'
        ...
    }
}
```

Just an idea. The above answers might do the same in other ways :)

Edit:

You could also use jQuery `.each()` like this:

```
classes.each(function(c) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'video'
        ...
        case 'slideshow'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe there is some perfomance gain in using a switch-case instead of if-else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hasClass`

[See this related post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617009/jquery-switch-case-plugin)  I think it does what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use if and the [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method:

```
if (active.hasClass('video')) {
}
else if {active.hasClass('slideshow')) {
}
```

If you need to do both (fall-through on the switch), remove the else so the if statements are independent.